# Button.setBackground(Drawable background) throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, exception, button

I'm implementing a simple method to add a `Button` to a `LinearLayout` programatically.

When I invoke the setBackground(Drawable background) method, the following `Error` is thrown:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.Button.setBackground`

**My addNewButton method:**

```
private void addNewButton(Integer id, String name) {

        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setId(id);
        b.setText(name);
        b.setTextColor(color.white);
        b.setBackground(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.orange_dot));
            //llPageIndicator is the Linear Layout.
        llPageIndicator.addView(b);
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You might be testing on an API below level 16 ([Jelly Bean](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html)).

The [setBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method is only available from that API level onwards.

I would try with [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) (deprecated) or [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) if that's the case.

For instance:

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Button one = new Button(this);
// mediocre
one.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
Button two = new Button(this);
// better
two.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: So, what is the solution to add the button's background programatically to lower than Api 16..without setBackGroundDrawable..which is deprecated...?

Comment: @EslamYousefMohammed edited my answer: try `setBackgroundResource`.

Comment: i have set android:minSdkVersion="9" in my manifest, why doesnt eclipse warn me about that?

Comment: @Mena i tried setBackgroundResource on framelayout but it is not working for me

Answer (score 3):

To create a homogeneous background for a View, you can create a drawable resource of type shape, and use that with the setBackgroundResource.

red_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"> 
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>    
</shape>
```

Activity:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_background);
```

But this will look pretty bad, flat and out of place. If you want a colored button that looks like a button, than you can either design it yourself (rounded corners, stroke, gradient fill...) or a fast and dirty solution is to add a PorterDuff filter to the button's background:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
PorterDuffColorFilter redFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
b.getBackground().setColorFilter(redFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since after Android 16 , the setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated, I suggested to checked before set code

you need to check current version of Android also

```
Button bProfile; // your Button
Bitmap bitmap; // your bitmap

if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    bProfile.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
}
else {
    bProfile.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnregister"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
                android:paddingVertical="5dp"
                style="@style/btn_register"
                android:text="Register"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

apply below code in Styles.xml file :

```
 <style name="btn_register">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">#009688</item>
        <item name="cornerRadius">20dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the theme from `Theme.MaterialComponents` to `Theme.AppCompat`

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `setBackground()`.
This method may be not available in your Android level.

Comment: FYI: In its current form, this is more of a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) than an answer. (That is probably why it was down voted). An "answer" should also include possible alternatives to solving the problem, [as did the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18559344/104223). See [Answer].