# Android button.setBackground

Tags: android, button, background, layerdrawable

I want to set background for the button. With `Android 4.1.2` everything works fine, but if launch with `Android 4.0` I've got an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.Button.setBackground
```

with code

```
LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
button.setBackground(composite);
```

So how can I set `LayerDrawable` background but with `Android 4.0` or earlier?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559248/button-setbackgrounddrawable-background-throws-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: create xml layer and set it for your button  button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.layer)); (setBackground come in api level 16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Both of the above answers are close you should really use

```
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

as Build.VERSION.SDK returns a string, and has been [deprecated since API 4](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
         LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
         button.setBackgroundDrawable(composite);
}else{
         LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
         button.setBackground(composite);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
     LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
     button.setBackgroundDrawable(composite);
}else{
     LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
     button.setBackground(composite);
}
```

setBackground drawable receives as a parameter (Drawable background)...

i hope helpp you...

Answer (score 0):

[setBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method is only available for API level 16 or above. You are probably using the method for API level below 16, that's why it's throwing `NoSuchMethodError`. You might want to try `setBackgroundDrawable` for lower API versions. Something like this would do:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
     LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
     button.setBackgroundDrawable(composite);
}else{
     LayerDrawable composite = new LayerDrawable(layers);
     button.setBackground(composite);
}
```

Comment: @DenisKotenko Good to know that! Don't forget to mark this answer correct :)