# setBackground in View cannot be applied

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to change the background when I click the button. The problem is it said setBackground in View cannot be applied to (int).

The code is:

```
    stopWaitGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == stopWaitGo){
                stopRed.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }
    });
```

The error is caused accordingly in this line

stopRed.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

How can I fix it?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559344/731938

Comment: got it! I use setBackgroundColor to solve it！